# Pass data between classes

Tags: java, android

I have two classes. 1st class extends AppCompatActivity and has all my data like arraylist, constants...
My 2nd class extends BaseAdapter.
Now the question is: I need to use some data from 1st class in my 2nd class how do I pass the data? I can't use Intents and I can't extend the 2nd class because it is already extends BaseAdapter.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can pass your data to the constructor of 2nd class from 1st class. Or you create public fields or public properties in 1st class and access from 2nd class

Comment: please give some Code snippets which help to get good answer

Answer (score 1):

you can pass data in constructor of second class like this:

`YourBaseAdapter adapter = new YourBaseAdapter(YourDataType1 data1, YourDatatype2 data2, ....)`

all you need to do is create matching constructor in `YourBaseAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

use `setters` and `getters` to set and get the date. Other way can be passing through constructor in case you do not want to change it once it has been constructed which is one aspect of immutability